# W3C validation Error: Bad value

Tags: html, url, w3c-validation, url-parsing

The W3C validation report me this error:

> Error: Bad value `http://form-integra.seekeo.com/tool-register-form/javascript?site_id=1273912&myCh=2&chIds[]=2&myGender=2-1&theme[login]=0&fb=1&style_id=8417&tracker=GrandeSexoNegro` for attribute `src` on element `script`: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.
>
> From line 166, column 1; to line 166, column 230
>
> ```
> mulario">↩<script type="text/javascript" src="http://form-integra.seekeo.com/tool-register-form/javascript?sit…Ids[]=2&amp;myGender=2-1&amp;theme[login]=0&amp;fb=1&amp;style_id=8417&amp;tracker=GrandeSexoNegro"></script>
> ```
>
> Syntax of URL:
>           Any URL. For example: `/hello`, `#canvas`, or `http://example.org/`. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as `%20`.

But I don´t understand where is the error and how to solve this.

How can fix this?

This is the complete URL:

```
<div class="elformulario"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://form-integra.seekeo.com/tool-register-form/javascript?site_id=1273912&amp;myCh=2&amp;chIds[]=2&amp;myGender=2-1&amp;theme[login]=0&amp;fb=1&amp;style_id=8417&amp;tracker=GrandeSe xoNegro"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: "Illegal character in query" - this tells all. check your url for ilegal characters

Comment: where is the "illegal character in query"?

Comment: Place URL from src here please.

Comment: I edited the main post with the complete url

Comment: "...GrandeSe xoNegro"
make it URL encoded.

Comment: Then, I must unify this characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C validator maintainer here. The specific problem in that URL is with the square brackets it contains; the "`[`" and "`]`" characters. Those aren’t [valid URL code points](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points) per the URL Standard.

I plan to get the URL checker in the validator updated to actually report the particular illegal characters it finds in URLs but it will be a while yet before I can get that refinement made.

Anyway the way to fix that URL is to run it through a tool that will [percent encode](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encode) (aka “URL encode“) any characters in the URL that aren’t [valid URL code points](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points).

One good online tool for percent-encoding URLs is Eric Meyer’s [URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).